# Qué hace esta línea de código escrito en php

Tags: php

Tengo un servidor web y mi hijo de vez en cuando lo administra y toquetea cosas. Normalmente siempre accedo a un archivo `.php`, hoy sin embargo no pude acceder y cuando revisé el archivo descubrí esta línea de código la cual es la causante de que no pueda entrar.

¿Alguien me dice qué es y cómo acceder al archivo PHP estando esa línea?

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['c5ee0b3033f88c8f89f3ab8b50edeca6'])) {header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');exit;} ?>
```

Comment: ¿Te fue útil alguna de las respuestas? Marca alguna como aceptada haciendo click en el check verde del costado de ellas, así ayudas a mantener la buena salud del sitio (% preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D

Answer (score 4):

Como complemento, creo que es más obvio el funcionamiento del script si lo indentamos:

```
<?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['c5ee0b3033f88c8f89f3ab8b50edeca6'])) {
   header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
   exit;
} 
?>
```

Si no existe una `cookie` llamada: `'c5ee0b3033f88c8f89f3ab8b50edeca6'`, se ejecuta lo que esta dentro del bloque, la función `header()` envía al header de la pagina cliente la indicación de que la página no existe. 
`exit` simplemente termina la ejecución del script.
Seguramente no se puede acceder puesto que la cookie generada en tu sesión es diferente.

Comment: "indentamos" -> sonaría mejor si decimos que le ponemos formato de sangría?

Comment: @fredyfx la "indentación" es un anglicismo muy común, me parece válido

Comment: @cesar concuerdo contigo

Comment: @fredyfx *poner formato de sangría*?, en qué año vives?

Comment: @MáximaAlekz sí, poner formato de sangría porque en aquel entonces (Febrero 1, de 2016) La comunidad de SOes estaba definiendo varias cosas de cómo llevar el sitio siendo una de ellas los "anglicismos", por eso el comentario como pregunta para "decidir", un abrazo :D

Comment: Hehe, creo que depende del lugar, en México he escuchado "sangría" que es como la [bebida](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sangr%C3%ADa_(bebida)), en Rumano por ejemplo es "zimțuire" que en realidad es como indentación, una determinada distancia con respecto al margen.

Comment: Ojalá permanezcan los anglicismos, y no veamos cosas como un Excel traducido... #JustSayin'

Answer (score 2):

**Lo que hace esa línea:**

Comprueba si existe una cookie con el nombre "c5ee0b3033f88c8f89f3ab8b50edeca6"; y si no existe, indica al navegador que la página no se ha encontrado y termina la ejecución del script.

---

**Para acceder al archivo:**

Comenta la línea (o al menos el `exit`).

Aunque esto podría crear problemas si el valor de la cookie se utiliza en alguna parte del código (se supone que la comprobación se ha puesto por un motivo).